# Elements not laying out as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

im trying to build a simple website consuming the flickr api, getting the fotos and the details, and showing the content with bootstrap, but something strange is happening and i dont know how to fix it, my code at the moment is **working like this:**

[image]

in this image, the 4th fotos div should be wrapped in the next row, and not fill the space that is left from the 3th,

**here is the effect that i want:**

[image]

**code html:**

```
<div class="row" id="results">

</div>
```

the container is there to, but i have more things above so its useless to put it here, the important div is there.

**code javascript relevant part**

```
var htmlText = "<div class='col-md-4 style='margin-top:200px'><img src =" + src + " width=" + width + " height=" + height + ">" +
"<p><b>título:  </b>:" + title + "</p>" + "<p><b>autor:  </b>" + owner + "</p>" + "<p><b>data:  </b>" + date + "</p>" + "<p><b>local:  </b>" + local

for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    htmlText += "<label style='border:1px solid grey;margin-left:10px'>" + $(tags[i]).attr('raw') + "</label>";
}

htmlText += "</div>";
$('#results').append(htmlText);
```

Ps: Sorry for my bad paint skills, and bad english :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After every 3rd block, add a block with `class="col-xs-12"` to force the others on a new row. If you want to have different numbers of columns for different viewports, you can even suppress this behavior by also adding the class `visible-md` to only go for 3 columns on medium width screens.

In the end your code would become:

```
var htmlText = "<div class='col-md-4 style='margin-top:200px'><img src =" + src + " width=" + width + " height=" + height + ">" +
"<p><b>título:  </b>:" + title + "</p>" + "<p><b>autor:  </b>" + owner + "</p>" + "<p><b>data:  </b>" + date + "</p>" + "<p><b>local:  </b>" + local

for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    htmlText += "<label style='border:1px solid grey;margin-left:10px'>" + $(tags[i]).attr('raw') + "</label>";
}

htmlText += "</div>";
$('#results').append(htmlText);

if (isThirdBlock) // Determine this somehow
    $('#results').append("<div class='col-xs-12'></div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your css file you need to have the display property of each of your columns set to 'inline-block' to get the effect you're looking for. Set vertical alignment to 'top' as well and everything should look like you want it to. Check the bootstrap docs for the display property and you'll find inline-block described.

Comment: still not working :/

Comment: Try using Clear CSS property to adjust the floating issues. Hope it may help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `table` `th` `td` in your HTML and then use position in CSS
Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Please do excuse me as I am not sure if you have any issues with using a new row after every 3 columns, however I shall mention it since no-one else has done so far.

You could add a "div class='row'" after every 3 column blocks. This should fix the problem.

Comment: hmmmm, by default bootstrap can use the same row and increase the size